# How to change a particular character of a string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

For instance I hava a varchar column and I need to change character number 3 to 'a' or character number 5 to 'c' etc. Is it possible to do it fast (e.g. O(1) in C/C++ with arr[3] = 'a')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to process the character fields in O(1). Actually, the only way I can think of is really a mess:

```
SELECT
  col,
  CONCAT(left(col, @index - 1), 'X', right(col, char_length(col) - @index)) val
FROM t, (SELECT @index := 2) init
```

EG:

```
|      COL |      VAL |
|----------|----------|
| Jonathan | JXnathan |
|   Martin |   MXrtin |
|  Charles |  CXarles |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/051fe/1).

Comment: Oh my god, it's totally trash, didn't mysql creators think of changing array elements? It's just an ordinary situation when you need to store an array. In my problem I need to store an array of little numbers so I decided to use strings and store numbers as 2 characters. I need to change one particular number, so I though of altering particular characters.

Comment: I agree. I'm not sure why you chose to use characters to store small numbers (you have many integer sizes to chose from). However, if you are going to keep the character field you could take a look at the [string manipulation functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace). I couldn't find any suitable one for this that would replace based on position

Comment: I mean I have an array with lots of small numbers and I've go lots of queries to change a particular number in this array and also queries to get the whole array. This way I thought it would be nice if I could store an array as a string and alter particular characters.

Comment: I don't fully get it yet. Anyway, storing an array in a field means a multivalued field which means that the table is not in first normal form. Denormalization should only be justified by performance reasons. Maybe you could fetch the whole array, process it in your language (C++, Java, etc) and then update the array field as a whole.

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote/ mark this answer as the correct one if it has helped you.